# Chef Vault Error - Could not find pivotal in users or clients

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks

Currently running AWS OpsWorks for Chef Automate, but running into what feels like many issues coming from a Chef Server only world.. Here is the exact error message:

```
WARNING: pivotal not found in users, trying clients.
ERROR: ChefVault::Exceptions::AdminNotFound: FATAL: Could not find pivotal in users or clients!
```

However, if I SSH into the EC2 instance, I return the user when running

```
sudo chef-server-ctl user-list
```

I also created the pivotal user with an automate-ctl command, but to no avail.

All I want to do is encrypt some AWS creds to read from an S3 bucket in a recipe. Why must it be so difficult?!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got a little confused as I am converting from Chef Server to Chef Automate. The solution was rather simple in the end. When setting up the AWS OpsWorks for Chef Automate you download a starter pack as the EC2 instance launches. This is different from downloading the "starter pack" when using Chef Server. The knife config and resulting *.pem file were for the pivotal user. Chef Vault works with Chef Server, and not Chef Automate. I SSH'd into the Linux AMI EC2 instance running Chef Automate and used chef-server-ctl to create myself a user with admin privileges and grabbed the corresponding private key when doing so.

```
sudo chef-server-ctl user-create ....
sudo chef-server-ctl org-user-add .... --admin
```

I then updated my local `knife.rb` file to reflect this for `node_name` and `client_key`. After that, the following command that was throwing the error before finally worked

```
knife vault create aws s3_bucket_keys -A "admin" .\data_bags\aws\s3_bucket_keys.json -M client
```

To use `-M client` by default, you can add this to your `knife.rb` file

```
knife[:vault_mode] = 'client'
```